# Cancel execution of command if it takes too long

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am currently working on a piece of software that uses an assembly from a different department.
I call a Method from this assembly like this:

```
using (var connection = (IConnection) Factory.GetObject(typeof (IConnection)))
```

The code used to work perfectly fine. But for the last few minutes it seemed like my program was doing nothing when I tried to launch it. Pressing pause while debugging showed me it got "stuck" at the line above.
My guess is they're just doing some maintenance or something but that's not the point here.
So I though it would be nice to tell the user what went wrong if the program doesn't start. Something simple like

```
MessageBox.Show("Could not connect", "Connection Error");
```

And then close the program. My question is:
**How do I terminate the execution of a command after a set amount of time and jump somewhere else?**
My guess would be moving it to a separate thread and then putting the calling thread to sleep for a few seconds after which it disposes of the extra thread if it isn't completed yet. But that seems *really* dirty to me and there's got to be a better way.

Comment: If your `IConnection` is `SqlConnection`, you can use default connection timeout provided with it.

Comment: @Kilanny even though the usage is very similar, it's not an SqlConnection and nobody seemed to bother implementing a timeout.

Comment: Otherwise use a `Timer` to check the execution, when timed-out it should terminate the job

Comment: `using` statement is there to tidy up after aborting the thread, at least in theory...

Comment: @slawekin a `using` block is used to automatically dispose of the specified object upon leaving the block. But that never happens since I don't get the object in the first place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question can be separated into two parts:

1. How to terminate the execution of a command?

The only way is to abort the thread. **But don't do it**. There is no guaranteed and safe way. There are such methods like Thread.Interrupt and Thread.Abort that can wake up the thread. But they will work only if the thread is in the WaitSleepJoin state and it hangs in managed code.

Seems like you already know it. But once again, if something inside the assembly hangs infinitely the execution of code then the thread is probably "gone". So you are right that the program should be closed.

2. ... jump somewhere else?

Good approach is using of TPL and async model.
Here is an extension method to wrap up any Task and expires after timeout.

```
public static async Task TimeoutAfter(this Task task, int millisecondsTimeout)
{
    if (task == await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(millisecondsTimeout)))
        await task;
    else
        throw new TimeoutException();
}
```

Then use it

```
try
{
    using (var result = await Task.Run(() => (IConnection)Factory.GetObject(typeof(IConnection))).TimeoutAfter(1000))
    {
        ...
    }
}
catch (TimeoutException ex)
{
    //timeout
}
```

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/11/10/10235834.aspx) you can find more information

Comment: Detailed answer giving directions to even more detail. I love it. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way of doing it without extra libraries or extension methods:

```
using ( var task = new Task<IConnection>( () => Factory.GetObject( typeof( IConnection ) ) ) )
{
    task.Start();

    if( !task.Wait( timeoutMilliseconds ) )
    {
        throw new TimeoutException();
    }

    IConnection result = task.Result;
}
```

`Task.Wait` does what you want, because you can throw an exception if it returns false (task didn't complete in time.)

It's even simpler if you have an Action that doesn't return something:

```
if ( !Task.Run( action ).Wait( timeoutMilliseconds ) )
{
    throw new TimeoutException();
}
```

Where `action` is some `Action` or lambda.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this, if a native timeout is not implemented, as you mentioned, is a separate thread to load it on.  Although this sounds like it'll be really dirty, it's as simple as (using Rx):

```
Task<IConnection> connectionTask = Observable.Start(() => Factory.GetObject(typeof (IConnection)), Scheduler.Default).Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).ToTask());
using (var connection = connectionTask.Result)
{
    ...
}
```

You can tweak the `Scheduler` if you don't want it to run on the threadpool.  It will throw a `TimeoutException` if the `Factory.GetObject` call takes longer than 20 seconds.

Comment: Same idea but a lot smoother. Thanks a lot. I surrounded it with a `try-catch` but when I try debugging, it says it will never reach the breakpoint that I placed inside `catch`. Seems weird to me, I'll have another look at this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *CancellationTokenSource* to set a timeout on the operation

```
var timeoutCts = new CancellationTokenSource();
try
{
    timeoutCts.CancelAfter(300000); // Cancel after 5 minutes
    // ... run your long term operation
}
catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
{
    // Handle the timeout
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=net-5.0#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Wait_System_Threading_CancellationToken_) from Microsoft

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Task t = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            long sum = 0;
            int n = 5000000;
            for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= n; ctr++)
            {
                int number = rnd.Next(0, 101);
                sum += number;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total:   {0:N0}", sum);
            Console.WriteLine("Mean:    {0:N2}", sum / n);
            Console.WriteLine("N:       {0:N0}", n);
        });
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150);
        if (!t.Wait(ts))
            Console.WriteLine("The timeout interval elapsed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Linking and copy pasting code from the link is not really an answer, next time you should post the link as a comment to the question

Comment: I thought it would make it easy for anyone to just copy the code and be done with it instead of opening the link which has a bit too much information in it. But ok.